# Implementing address search in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, uisearchbar

I need to implement a screen where my ios application will determine my current location and geocode it to a text field. I am able to do this using CLLocationManager in ios.
User can also input his other address into the search bar and the application should now show all the addresses matching. Can you help me as how can I implement this second requirement?
Thanks!

Comment: use google Map API..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same concept that I follow in my project using Google API

```
Google API:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=\(searchString.text)&key=(YOUR_API_KEY)"
```

**First, we need to add functionality for your textfield**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
searchString.addTarget(self, action: "whiletyping:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}



func whiletyping(textField:UITextField)
    {
        getPlaces(searchString.text)
    }

func getPlaces(searchString: String) {
        var request = requestForSearch(searchString)
        println("the URL :\(request)")

        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            self.handleResponse(data, response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: error)

            println("the response : \(response)")
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func handleResponse(data: NSData!, response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, error: NSError!) {
        if let error = error {
            println("GooglePlacesAutocomplete Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if response == nil {
            println("GooglePlacesAutocomplete Error: No response from API")
            return
        }

        if response.statusCode != 200 {
            println("GooglePlacesAutocomplete Error: Invalid status code \(response.statusCode) from API")
            return
        }

        var serializationError: NSError?
        var json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
            data,
            options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,
            error: &serializationError
            ) as! NSDictionary

        if let error = serializationError {
            println("GooglePlacesAutocomplete Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        // Perform table updates on UI thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

            if let predictions = json["predictions"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
                self.places = predictions.map { (prediction: AnyObject) -> Place2 in
                    return Place2(
                        id: prediction["id"] as! String,
                        description: prediction["description"] as! String,
                        place_id: prediction["place_id"] as! String
                    )
                }


            }
        })
    }


    func requestForSearch(searchString: String) -> NSURLRequest {
        let params = [
            "input": searchString,
            "type": "(\(placeType.description))",
            //"type": "",
            "key": "**YOUR API KEY**"
        ]

        return NSMutableURLRequest(
            URL: NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?\(query(params))")!
        )
    }

    func query(parameters: [String: AnyObject]) -> String {
        var components: [(String, String)] = []
        for key in sorted(Array(parameters.keys), <) {
            let value: AnyObject! = parameters[key]

            components += [(escape(key), escape("\(value)"))]
        }

        return join("&", components.map{"\($0)=\($1)"} as [String])
    }

    func escape(string: String) -> String {
        let legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped: CFStringRef = ":/?&=;+!@#$()',*"

         //return CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, string, nil, legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped, CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue)

        return CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, string, nil, legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped, CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue) as String

    }
```

Output:

```
let place = self.places[0]
address1=place.description

place = self.places[1]
address2=place.description

place = self.places[2]
address3=place.description

place = self.places[3]
address4=place.description

place = self.places[4]
address5=place.description
```

Comment: Its not working, can you give me detailed steps as how have you progressed?

Comment: In my project, I have placed textfiled and add target function, while typing my search string in my textfield that will be call getPlaces(textfiled.text). Then after getting results from the function I will show that result in my table view